# How to Gradually Change the Speed of Audio in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In the new Blender update of 4.0, they changed the workflow of the speed control of audio in the video editor. There used to be a **"Speed Factor"** value, on audio strips. You could add keyframes to that value and easily edit the speed of the audio.

**In Blender 4.0**, there is now a **"Show Retiming Keys"** option to change the speed of audio. You can select the audio strip, and press I, and choose, **add Retiming key**. You can then drag around the retiming keys, to change the speed of the audio.

However, when i add keyframes, **it changes the audio to a consistent speed** between the keyframes. I want to be able to gradually change the speed, so there is a smooth transition between the audio speeding up and slowing down. **And I want it to also match the speed of the video, if I slow down or speed up a video.**

**How is this done with the new audio speed controls in Blender?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Sync Audio-Video Retiming**
Select video and audio strip and create a MetaStrip (Ctrl+G)

**Smooth Transition Retiming**
Check *Blender Manual > Retiming >* **[Smooth Transition](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/video_editing/edit/montage/editing.html#smooth-transitions)** ... simply select a retiming key between two segments and search for Add Speed Transition.

[image]

... at left -bottom corner change value to something.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Sorry for the late reply. I tried that, but for me, it didn't make the speed change smoothly, it was still at a consistent speed. Also for some reason, its making the audio glitch out and sound really weird and distorted, and have lots of artifacts. Then Blender always crashes and closes after a short time, every time I try to edit the keyframes. It seems to me like there are still a lot of bugs, since this is a newer feature of Blender. Hoping it will be fixed in a later version.